# Use implicit namespace on template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Example code

```
namespace many {
    namespace namespaces {
        class Bar {
        };

        template<typename T>
        void foo() {
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy but to call `foo` with the template argument `Bar` it necessary (if no using directive is active) to write

```
many::namespaces::foo<many::namespaces::Bar>();
```

Which feels kind of silly when I know that all allowed types are in the namespace `many::namespaces`. So my question is if there is some way to implicitly lookup Bar in the correct namespace? That way I would be able to write

```
many::namespaces::foo<Bar>();
```

Which would be pretty handy especially in situation where I have multiple template arguments to pass. I know that ADL would allow

```
foo<many::namespaces::Bar>();
```

but that looks kind of weird to me.

So anyone knows if a macro-free solution exists for this?

Comment: Use a `using` statement (`using namespace <namespace>` or `using = <type>` will do).

Comment: The idea is to NOT use a using directive. I want something like a using directive which is only active for the function call.

Comment: Actually, ADL only works on functions that take an argument of that user-defined type. It won't allow the call syntax you spoke of.

Comment: AFAIK I don't think it's possible to do such a thing without using a macro, or a type alias of some sort.

Comment: Ah true - was a mistake while writing the post. Thought about creating a "tag"-type which gets passed as non-template argument, so the template arguments gets deduced => ADL works

Comment: Yeah, I think the closest you can get is `foo(wrap<many::namespaces::Bar>());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a solution does not exist:

A template type parameter does neither establish its own scope, nor does it have any ADL-like lookup rules. Also, you cannot pass it any arbitrary token, but you need to pass it a type.

Therefore, whatever you pass it must be findable in the surrounding scope of your call. You can either qualify it, or pull it into one of the surrounding namespaces via `using` / `typedef` directives.

While ADL may seem a viable alternative (if you add a parameter) that means that you have something at hand whose type will cause the ADL to achieve the desired result. It should be noted that in that case you just wrote the type somewhere else in this scope and you can reuse it with `decltype` (and potentially a bit of `type_traits` magic).

P.S.: While macros can achieve the desired result (by establishing an additional scope and inserting a using namespace directive in that specific scope, or by prepending a full qualification) you explicitly did not want one.

Comment: I'm accepting this as answer - If someone actually has a solution I will change it